# Applications and Natural Occurrences of Prime Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, applications

I'm fascinated by prime numbers, and over the years, I've found multiple applications and natural occurrences for them.  But can anyone suggest some alternatives that aren't in my list?

**Applications of Prime Numbers**

- Public key cryptography algorithms
- The lengths of hash tables (not recommended)
- Prime polynomials can be used for hash functions and CRC algorithms
- Programs that search for large prime numbers can be used as “torture tests” for compilers, multitasking operating systems, memory, processors, etc.
- Pseudo-random-number generators
- Hard disk interleaving
- Error-correction codes (quadratic residue codes)
- Since no known natural process generates prime numbers, extraterrestrials might use them at the beginning of a radio transmission so we can distinguish it from a natural process (as in Carl Sagan's *Contact*).
- Generating [organically tiling images](http://designfestival.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/)

**Applications of Coprimality**

- If the number of teeth on a sprocket and the number of links in a chain are coprime, then the sprocket-chain system will experience even wear (cyclical wear will be minimized).
- Nanotech symmetrical sleeve bearings, in which the outer sleeve has m-fold rotational symmetry and the inner sleeve has n-fold rotational symmetry, would in theory function most smoothly when m and n are coprime. (Nanosystems, K. Eric Drexler, p. 286)

**Natural Occurrences of Prime Numbers**

- The 13- and 17-year life cycles of periodical cicadas (genus magicicada) may be an evolutionary advantage (minimizing exposure to predators and competing broods).

Answer (score 3):

this is somewhat related (but different) to pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs):

The $s$-dimensional Halton sequence is a quasi-Monte Carlo sequence which is a collection of van der Corput sequences in bases $\{b_{1}, b_{2}, \ldots, b_{s}\}$. The bases $b_{i}$ are chosen so that they are pairwise mutually prime. Thus, the natural choice is to use the first $s$ prime numbers.

Quasi-Monte Carlo sequences are number-theoretic sequences designed to give good uniformity in the $s$-dimensional cube. There are randomization techniques which allow them to be to used in simulation like one would with regular PRNGs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a class of error-correcting codes called quadratic residue codes - these are based on the quadratic residues modulo a prime.

Comment: The quadratic residue codes include the perfect ternary and binary Golay codes, which provide points of entry to the realm of the sporadic groups...

Answer (score 3):

> The lengths of hash tables

This is something of a myth. If you have a good hash function, the number-theoretical properties of your table's modulus are irrelevant; conversely, if you have a bad hash function, a prime modulus does little to salvage it.

Indeed, a power-of-two modulus has a lot to recommend itself in practice: you can perform reduction of $x$ modulo a power of two $n$ in one processor cycle using the identity $x\ MOD\ n = x\ AND\ (n-1)$.

Look at the highest-performing hash table implementations and you will find they use powers of two. Examples include Google's [sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/source/browse/trunk/src/google/sparsehash/sparsehashtable.h) and Sean Barrett's hash table from [his article](http://nothings.org/computer/judy/) on Judy arrays.

Comment: I've added a "not recommended" comment at the end of that example, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a semi-serious application of prime numbers, how about "establishing communication with aliens"? See Carl Sagan's novel "Contact".

Comment: Heh, I think both Carl Sagan and Arthur C. Clarke made mention of alien communication. Added. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this one is too frivolous, but sometimes, at Chinese restaurants, I get 5 shumai or 7 peking ravioli, instead of 6 or 8, and I've always wondered if that was a deliberate ploy to entice people to order more servings!

Comment: I remember ordering appetizers at several restaurants that couldn't be divided evenly...

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say this, but the Yan et al. paper seems a bit crackpotty.  ([abstract](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1943145), [brief discussion at Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=RbEz-_D7sAUC&pg=PA426&lpg=PA426&dq=yan+amino+acid+prime&source=bl&ots=Klq1DNlOHa&sig=JQrVfc32HaZb1H_3ChsKqrGMGRY&hl=en&ei=P37aSq68BMLT8Ab6kdS3BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CBoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=yan%20amino%20acid%20prime&f=false) from the [book by Crandall and Pomerance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387252827).)  I suspect it's just based on some numerical coincidences.

The others are nice examples, though.